# GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Insufficient buffer size

Tags: javascript, webgl, webgl2

i'm trying to paint some models 3D using javascript with webgl2 and i can't undestand the problem i get:

```
[.WebGL-00000188C244F2D0] GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Insufficient buffer size.
```

I suposse it is about the buffers but y don't know why, i have the buffers like that:

```
 if (positions && positions.length != 0) {
    const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(positions), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
}
```

Model 3D:

positions: 1146
normals: 1146
uvs: 72
indices: 8360

If you need more code say to me!

Thanks!

Comment: Arguably there isn't enough code to go on. Have you tried calling gl.getError]() after each function to find out exactly which function is causing this error? In any case the error means you tried to write (bufferSubData, texSubData) or read (drawArrays, drawElements) more data than exists. Indices that are too large, a count that would read past the end of a buffer, etc... suspicious that you used a count of 4 for position. Most apps use 3. Also that you hard coded the location to 0 but maybe you manaully set it to 0 in the shader.

Comment: What's [the smallest program](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-smallest-programs.html) you can make that repoduces the error?

Comment: I had a similar error. My issue was that I forgot to re-bind the correct buffer to `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` before calling `drawElements(...)`. The one that was bound to that buffer was for another program / different vertices.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is gl.vertexAttribPointer, you are giving 0  at the beginning, ut I guess you should look up first the coords of your variable in the shader with getAttribLocation and then pass it to that function